# Need SQL Query to fetch data from a table for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where there are columns like ID, USER, PreviousValue, CurrentValue, Date.

Need a query that will give the latest current value and the rest columns could be of any user based on user queried for.

Example: If the table has last entry for user A, and query is for User B, The ID, User, previous Value, Date should be returned for user B but the current Value should be for user A.

```
ID   Previous  Current  User     createdOn
1    RED       BLUE     System   14-MAR-2020
2    GREEN     YELLOW   ADMIN    12-MAR-2020 

IF I query for ADMIN as user the row returned should contain  below data:

ID   Previous  Current  User     createdOn
2    GREEN     BLUE     ADMIN    12-MAR-2020
```

As the latest row was added on 14 MARCH the current value should come from that row, rest all data should be of the user I queried for.

Comment: Better if give example with sample table structure

Comment: I have already provided the column names, do you need example data as well?

Comment: With example data and example output would be nice.. and please post as text and not image, thanks

Comment: *I have already provided the column names* Provide CREATE TABLE script, add INSERT INTO script with some sample data and desired result for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery to get the latest current value should do it.

```
select
  Id,
  Previous,
  User,
  CreatedOn,
  (
    select Current
    from users
    order by CreatedOn desc
    limit 1
   ) as Current
from users
where user = ?
order by createdon desc
limit 1
```

Comment: @ShubhamParmar please be aware, you appear to have an issue with your CreatedOn column that may result in the incorrect values being retrieved by this answer, I provided a fix in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### WARNING! Date Format Problem

I strongly urge you to convert the `CreadedOn` column to a `DATE` data-type, instead of `VARCHAR`, in order to retrieve the appropriate ordering of values by date.
Otherwise `14-MAR-2020` will be considered later than `11-DEC-2020`.

**Issue Example [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7W1VpZYHsmDxhUdnAbs7bx/0)**

**Schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Previous` VARCHAR(5),
  `Current` VARCHAR(6),
  `User` VARCHAR(18),
  `createdOn` VARCHAR(20)
);


INSERT INTO users
  (`ID`, `Previous`, `Current`, `User`, `createdOn`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'System', '14-MAR-2020'),
  ('2', 'GREEN', 'YELLOW', 'ADMIN', '12-MAR-2020'),
  ('3', 'GREEN', 'PURPLE', 'System', '11-DEC-2020'),
  ('4', 'GREEN', 'YELLOW', 'System', '10-MAR-2020');
```

**Other answer query** https://stackoverflow.com/a/61316029/1144627

```
select
  Id,
  Previous,
  User,
  CreatedOn,
  (
    select Current
    from users
    order by CreatedOn desc
    limit 1
   ) as Current
from users
where `user` = 'ADMIN'
order by createdon desc
limit 1;
```

```
| Id  | Previous | User  | CreatedOn   | Current |
| --- | -------- | ----- | ----------- | ------- |
| 2   | GREEN    | ADMIN | 12-MAR-2020 | BLUE    |
```

> **Expected Current of PURPLE**

---

To fix the issue with the date sorting, you will need to modify your table using the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

It is important to note that comparing with `STR_TO_DATE` in your query instead of updating the column will cause a full-table scan, comparing every record in the table.

**Example [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QcWevgyR3VM5rzhAEDpQw/0)**

```sql
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN createdOn_Date DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE users
SET CreatedOn_Date = STR_TO_DATE(CreatedOn, '%d-%b-%Y')
WHERE CreatedOn_Date IS NULL;


ALTER TABLE users
DROP COLUMN CreatedOn,
CHANGE COLUMN CreatedOn_Date CreatedOn DATE;
```

Then display your records in your desired format, use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

**Other Answer Query** https://stackoverflow.com/a/61316029/1144627

```
select
  Id,
  Previous,
  User,
  DATE_FORMAT(CreatedOn, '%d-%b-%Y') AS CreatedOn,
  (
    select Current
    from users
    order by CreatedOn desc
    limit 1
  ) as Current
from users
where `user` = 'ADMIN'
order by createdon desc
limit 1;
```

**Result**

```
| Id  | Previous | User  | CreatedOn   | Current |
| --- | -------- | ----- | ----------- | ------- |
| 2   | GREEN    | ADMIN | 12-Mar-2020 | PURPLE  |
```